# How to remove bootstrap's outline in form-control class?

Tags: html, css

My html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>homepage</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                                data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="d-flex">
                        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

I am using boostrap navbar,to design the template normally for my practice as i am new to bootstrap, i have recently learned css,but i got one problem that is,i am not able to remove bootstrap's outline, by the following css i have done for it.

My css file

```
input.form-control {
  outline: none;
}
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the `box shadow`, which you are saying `outline`.

set the following css:

```
.navbar .form-control:focus {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

It may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use inline style on the element u are targeting it overides all the external style
For example

```
<input class="form-control" style="outline:none;box-shadow:none;" >
```

Comment: Both `outline` and `box-shadow` should none.